# Databinding to a custom control in Expression Blend

Tags: c#, custom-controls, expression-blend

I created a custom controll in expression Blend and added a property. I found the property in Blend, but the option for create a databinding isn't available. What do I have to make that I can add databindings through Blend?

Code Property:

```
    public string TileText
    {
        get { return this.labelTileText.Text; }
        set { this.labelTileText.Text = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enable databinding on a property of a custom control, you need to create a dependency property for that property.

The property:

```
public string TileText { 
     get { return this.labelTileText.Text; } 
     set { this.labelTileText.Text = value; } 
}
```

Dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TileTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
"TileText", typeof(String), typeof(ClassName), new UIPropertyMetadata("default value", callBack));
```

And then you should implement that callBack function that to be called whenever 'TileText' property is changed.